# Flex DataGrid Not Updating When Loading New Excel File

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, filereference, as3xls

I am new to Flex coding and am trying to import an Excel file so that I can work with it later.  I've cobbled enough together from the two articles below so that I can successfully load one Excel file and display the contents in a DataGrid.

However, if I try to upload a second Excel file, the contents of the DataGrid don't change.  (And I end up truncating one row from the top, when the code re-writes the headers to the DataGrid.)

1. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/21/uploading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class
2. http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/wiki/Tutorial

Full code is below.  Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Corey

PS: There is a glitch in how I'm handling the headers, as any formulae in the Excel sheet still reference the original row after I remove the headers. They are pointing to one row below where they should.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" xmlns="*" creationComplete="init()" height="727" width="777">

<mx:Script>

    <![CDATA[
        import com.as3xls.xls.ExcelFile;
        import com.as3xls.xls.Sheet;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        //Based on example from: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/21/uploading-files-in-flex-using-the-filereference-class/

        private var fileRef:FileReference;
        private var ba:ByteArray;
        private var xlFile:ExcelFile;
        private var hdrs:Array;
        private var runOnce:Boolean;


        [Bindable]
        private var xlsheet:ArrayCollection;

        private const FILE_URL:String = "http://localhost:8500/fileref/uploader.cfm";
        private const XLS_FILTER:FileFilter = new FileFilter("EXCEL FILES (*.xls, *.xlsx)", "*.xls; *.xlsx");
        private const TXT_FILTER:FileFilter = new FileFilter("TEXT FILES (*.txt, *.csv, *.tsv)", "*.txt; *.csv; *.tsv");
        private const ALL_FILTER:FileFilter = new FileFilter("ALL FILES (*.*)", "*.*");

        private function init():void {
            fileRef = new FileReference();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileRef_select);
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, fileRef_progress);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileRef_complete);

            ba = new ByteArray();
            xlFile = new ExcelFile();
            hdrs = new Array();
            xlsheet = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        private function browseAndUpload():void {
            fileRef.browse([XLS_FILTER, TXT_FILTER, ALL_FILTER]);
            message.text = "";


        }

        private function fileRef_select(evt:Event):void {
            try {
                message.text = "size (bytes): "+ numberFormatter.format(fileRef.size);
                message.text += " | " + fileRef.name

                //Alert.show (fileRef.name);
                fileRef.load();

            } catch(err:Error) {
                message.text = "ERROR: zero-byte file";
            }
        }

        private function fileRef_progress(evt:ProgressEvent):void{
            progressBar.visible = true;
        }

        private function fileRef_complete(evt:Event):void{

            try {
                message.text += " (complete)";
                progressBar.visible = false;
                grid.initialize()               

                ba=fileRef["data"];
                xlFile.loadFromByteArray(ba);
                xlsheet = xlFile.sheets[0].values;

                hdrs =  xlsheet[0];
                xlsheet.removeItemAt(0);

                grid.dataProvider = xlsheet;
            } catch (err:Error) {
                message.text = "An error occurred";
            }

        }

        private function updateHeaders(): void {
            if(grid.columnCount>=1){
                for (var i:int=0; i<=grid.columnCount-1; i++){
                    grid.columns[i].headerText=hdrs[i];
                }

            }
        }

    ]]>

</mx:Script>

<mx:NumberFormatter id="numberFormatter"/>
<mx:Button label="Upload File"
           click="browseAndUpload();" labelPlacement="left"/>
<mx:Label id="message"/>
<mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar"
                indeterminate="true"
                visible = "false"/>

<mx:DataGrid id="grid"
    updateComplete="updateHeaders();"/>


</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Appologies, just noticed that some of the code got truncated at the bottom, tho I suspect nothing of significance to the issue.  Also a few excess variables left over from attempts to solve this...

Comment: I fixed the code formatting; sometimes StackOverflow gets weird on code formatting.  I'm not sure why grid.initialize() is called; you should never need to call that manually.  If the DataGrid isn't changing it most likely means that the dataProvider is either not getting changed or is being replaced w/ the same element.  The reason the top item is being removed is because of xmlSheet.removeItemAt(0).  Sounds like you're not selecting a new file or that the fileRef is not getting a refernece to the new file.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, thanks for touching up the code formatting.  Couldn't see how to do that myself.

Comment: I attempted the `grid.initialize()` call in an attempt to flush out old values.  Clearly didn't clean up completely before I posted. (sorry).

I knew that was the issue with the `xlSheet.removeItemAt(0)` call, causing the rows to be truncated. I feel like that's a clue to my problem.  Seems like `xlSheet` is not being updated, but I'm not sure if that's a problem with the `fileRef.load()` call, or `xlSheet` not accepting a new value.  The COMPLETE event is being fired; still no new data.

Comment: Is the problem that the var isn't being updated or the DataGrid? IE if you break after the file is loaded, do you see the expected values?

Comment: .. and what happens if you make the variable Bindable and link it to the DataGrid?

Comment: @corey_s You can format code w/ the curly bracket button in th editor.  I think you did that.  But, sometimes the code formatting will "get lost" especially if you hit enter or tweak things after signing in.  Looks like someone already posted your solution.

Comment: One other thing, to refres the grid; you should make use of the invalidation methods: invalidateDisplayList(), invalidateSize(), and invalidateProperties().  The MX List based classes also have an invalidateList() method.  Spark classes also have an invalidateSkinState() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error in your code is that the xlFile object is incremented each time you load a new stuff. So the sheets[0] is always the same! 
If your files have 3 sheets, then the first sheet of the new file is in the sheets[3] object.

To correct this try to initiate the xlFile object every time you load a new file. I have done it by me and it works perfectly! Here is my code (I have wiped some lines to simplify it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            layout="vertical" 
            height="727" width="777" creationComplete="init()">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.as3xls.xls.ExcelFile;
        import com.as3xls.xls.Sheet;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private var fileRef:FileReference;
        private var ba:ByteArray;
        private var xlFile:ExcelFile;
        private var hdrs:Array;
        private var runOnce:Boolean;

        [Bindable]private var xlsheet:ArrayCollection;

        private const XLS_FILTER:FileFilter = new FileFilter("EXCEL FILES (*.xls)", "*.xls");

        private function init():void 
        {
            fileRef = new FileReference();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileRef_select);
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, fileRef_progress);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileRef_complete);

            ba = new ByteArray();
            hdrs = new Array();
            xlsheet = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        private function browseAndUpload():void {
            fileRef.browse([XLS_FILTER]);
            message.text = "";
        }

        private function fileRef_select(evt:Event):void {
            try {
                message.text = "size (bytes): "+ fileRef.size;
                message.text += " | " + fileRef.name
                fileRef.load();
            } catch(err:Error) {
                message.text = "ERROR: zero-byte file";
            }
        }

        private function fileRef_progress(evt:ProgressEvent):void{
            progressBar.visible = true;
        }

        private function fileRef_complete(evt:Event):void{
            try {
                xlFile = new ExcelFile();

                message.text += " (complete)";
                progressBar.visible = false;

                ba=fileRef["data"];
                xlFile.loadFromByteArray(ba);
                xlsheet = xlFile.sheets[0].values;

                hdrs =  xlsheet[0];
                xlsheet.removeItemAt(0);

                grid.dataProvider = xlsheet;
            } catch (err:Error) {
                message.text = "An error occurred";
            }
        }

        private function updateHeaders(): void {
            if(grid.columnCount>=1){
                for (var i:int=0; i<=grid.columnCount-1; i++){
                    grid.columns[i].headerText=hdrs[i];
                }
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Button label="Upload File" click="browseAndUpload();" labelPlacement="left"/>
<mx:Label id="message"/>
<mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar" indeterminate="true" visible = "false"/>
<mx:DataGrid id="grid" updateComplete="updateHeaders();"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: awesome...  That did it.  Thanks!  I figured it had to be something simple like that.  Now I just need to find a better way to handle the headers so any formulae don't get messed up.

Comment: missed the hashtag in the last comment.  Just wanted to pass on my thanks!